# PDO: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens...but the counts DO match up

Tags: php, pdo

I'm getting what should be a clear-cut error message:

```
Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
```

I've gotten it before, and it's always because I've forgotten a colon or because the number of bound variables didn't match the number of tokens (imagine that).

In today's case, I'm not able to figure out why I'm getting this error. I have six bound variables, six colons and six tokens. var_dumping before binding outputs proper values for $this->productId and all the $this->contents[] values, so everything is correct and non-empty going into the binding process.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
$sql = 'insert into courses 
        (product_id, title, price, length, body_about, body_outline, body_profile, body_prerequisites, status_id) 
        values 
        (:product_id, :title, "0", "0", :body_about, :body_outline, :body_profile, :body_prerequisites, "1")';

$s -> bindValue(':product_id', $this->productId);
$s -> bindValue(':title', $this->contents['title']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_about', $this->contents['overview']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_outline', $this->contents['outline']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_profile', $this->contents['audience']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_prerequisites', $this->contents['prerequisites']);               
$s -> execute();
```

Does anything obvious stand out to you?

Comment: Where is the `prepare` statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11489714/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-ma)

Comment: Nah, not a duplicate of that. I forgot the prepare statement, so the answer is very different :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = 'insert into courses 
        (product_id, title, price, length, body_about, body_outline, body_profile, body_prerequisites, status_id) 
        values 
        (:product_id, :title, "0", "0", :body_about, :body_outline, :body_profile, :body_prerequisites, "1")';

$s = $db -> prepare($sql);               // NOTE THIS
$s -> bindValue(':product_id', $this->productId);
$s -> bindValue(':title', $this->contents['title']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_about', $this->contents['overview']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_outline', $this->contents['outline']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_profile', $this->contents['audience']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_prerequisites', $this->contents['prerequisites']);               
$s -> execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the PDO statement `$s` with prepare before binding to it.

```
// 1. setup the connection
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

// 2. write your sql
$sql = 'insert into courses (product_id, title, price, length, body_about, body_outline, body_profile, body_prerequisites, status_id)  values (:product_id, :title, "0", "0", :body_about, :body_outline, :body_profile, :body_prerequisites, "1")';

// 3. generate the prepared statement object
$s = $db->prepare($sql);

// 4. NOW, you can bind values...
$s -> bindValue(':product_id', $this->productId);
$s -> bindValue(':title', $this->contents['title']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_about', $this->contents['overview']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_outline', $this->contents['outline']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_profile', $this->contents['audience']);
$s -> bindValue(':body_prerequisites', $this->contents['prerequisites']);    

// 5. Finally execute the statement!           
$s -> execute()
```